# Relational database in django in a popup form

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, bootstrap-modal

I have two tables in a django database which are as follows:

Manufacturer

[image: IMG1 - Manufacturer]

and

Transporter

[image]

Both of these tables are filled by their respective forms. Now I have shown the data from Manufacturer onto a board like this and added a "BID NOW!" button too.

[image]

When I click this button a popup opens which have all the prefilled entries with **BID** field and a submit and cancel button. Like this:-

[image]

Now I want that  when i enter a bid and press the submit button it should update Load_ID(on which we are bidding), Transporter_ID(bidder) and bid_amount and an automatic bid_id in a table.

How do I do that ? and which fields should be made one-to-many/many-to-one ?

Here is the code for manufacturer board:

```
class ManufacturerBoardModel(models.Model):
  From = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
  To = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
  Type = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
  Length = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
  Weight = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
  Numberoftrucks = models.IntegerField(null=True)
  MaterialType = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=100)
  Loadingtime = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

def _str_(self):
    return self.Origin
```

Answer (score 1):

Since a particular manufacture board can have many biddings we can have manufacturer board as the foreign key in the bidding model.
Unique id (uuid) can be used as a bidding key.
Transporter can have many bidding as well hence it is also foreign key. But if you want that one transporter can bid on manufacturer board only one time you can also place a unique constraint on manufacturer_board and transporter fields.

```
class Bidding(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    manufacturer_board = models.ForeignKey(ManufacturerBoardModel)
    transporter = models.ForeignKey(Transporter)
    amount = models.FloatField(default=0)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('manufacturer_board', 'transporter')
```